# UIView with round corners has black background

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to create a UIView with round corners the round corners are rendering perfectly but there is an odd black background behind the view. How do I get rid of the black background?

**CODE**

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// The background rectange for main view
let backgroundRectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
// Main view
let mainView = UIView(frame: backgroundRectangle)
// Color of the main view
mainView.backgroundColor = .darkGray
// Corner radius
mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
mainView.layer.masksToBounds = false
// Present the view to Playground's live view
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = mainView
```

**RENDERED UI**

[image: UIVIEW]

**EDIT**

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// Holder rectangle
let holderRectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
// Holder view
let holderView = UIView(frame: holderRectangle)
// The background color of the holder view is clear
holderView.backgroundColor = .clear

// Main rectangle
let mainRectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
// Main view
let mainView = UIView(frame: mainRectangle)
// The background color of the main view is black
mainView.backgroundColor = .white
// Create a corner radius for the main view
mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 30
mainView.layer.masksToBounds = false

// Make the main view a subview of the holder view
holderView.addSubview(mainView)

// Present the holder view in the live view
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = holderView
```

Comment: The view behind your `mainView` has the black color. Put `mainView` inside some other view with a different color and you will see the different color. Your `mainView` is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because, there is no other view present behind your `mainView`. Please add a view behind `mainView` or embed your `mainView` into `UIView` assign a background color of your choice to the newly created view. Thats it your issue resolved.

Comment: replace this `holderView.backgroundColor = .clear` by this `holderView.backgroundColor = .white`

Comment: solved! thanks. For those using the Swift Playground and want a transparent background for the view that is behind the main view, you can set the color to the RGB value: 247, 247, 247.

Comment: @NikhilRaghavendra that isn't a transparent background. That sounds like you are matching the color of the background, which isn't quite the same thing. Instead, try setting the background color to be `.clear` instead.